# How to change position of objects in powerpoint?

Tags: vba

I am brand new to the community and to VB programming. Started learning about an hour ago. Sorry if this is a silly question.

I am trying to simplify life by changing the position of an "object" (like a header or text box) in powerpoint with a macro. I have done so successfully, but I am wondering if there is a way to do all the headers at once?

This is what I have. It works, but I don't want to do it 100s of times.

```
Sub Headers()

Dim X As Double

X = 72

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
  .height = 0.94 * (X)
  .width = 12.01 * (X)
  .left = 0.67 * (X)
  .top = 0.44 * (X)
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks :)